# if else condition as specified below

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a table

| ID | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AD | A |
| 2 | ASDF | B |
| 3 | ASg | C |
| 4 | hsdfg | B |
| 5 | dfh | D |

I want to show error message if city is not equal to either A or C (remember one name can have only one city)

if I write

```
if(name!="A")
{
    show message
}

if(name!="C")
{
    show message
}
```

The above code is wrong because even if the student is having city C then first if run and it show message it should not show it should check the second if and then show , remember only one city for one student

Comment: Could you please [edit] post to clarify how title (talking about if-else) relates to the body of the post that does not have a single mentioning of "else"? (Please format code as code while updating the post, ideally with real C# code like `Console.WriteLine("Match");` instead of "show message" pseudocode)

Comment: `if (name != "A" && name != "C") { show message }`

Comment: Many people first ask humans, then Google. While the correct order is the opposite.

Comment: && cannot be use as it will require both to be true at the same time and I will have one city associated with one student either it could be A or C but not both for one student.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to check both cities and show the result.

```
if (name != "A" && name != "C") {show message};
```

Edit: Thanks Tim

Comment: Needs to be `&&`, otherwise it's always true

Comment: && cannot be use as it will require both to be true at the same time and I will have one city associated with one student either it could be A or C but not both for one student.